# How to initialize a UIView using SuperView of a SubView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have a UILabel that is the subview of a UIView, I would like to know how to use this UILabel to cast a new temporary UIView so that I can access its values and or its superview.

to explain my object I have a UIScrollView which contains a UIView which in turn contains a UILabel, I would like to know how I can access the UIScrollView attributes when all I have access to is the UILabel.

This is how I created the object

```
UIScrollView *containerScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 77.0)];
insertView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    insertView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, scrollWidth+10, 77.0);
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 5.0, 40.0, 40.0];

[insertView addSubView:myLabel];
[containerScrollView addSubView:insertView];
```

Then I have a method that I am using to detect the new touch, add a value into the UILabel then check to see if the next UILabel is in frame or not. if it isn't then I am going to hopefully write some code to move the UIScrollViews scroll position.

this is that method

```
- (void) SymbolButtonPressed:(NSString *)selectedString {

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:currentlySelectedTag];

    if ([selectedString isEqualToString:@"Blank"]) {
        [label setText:@" "];
        [cutFieldsMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:currentlySelectedTag-1 withObject:@" "]; //replace first string with second string in the array

    } else {
        NSRange slashRange = [selectedString rangeOfString:@"/"];
        if (slashRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            NSString *updatedString = [[selectedString substringToIndex:slashRange.location] stringByAppendingString:@"+"];

            [label setText:updatedString];
            [cutFieldsMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:currentlySelectedTag-1 withObject:updatedString]; //replace first string with second string in the array

        } else {
            [label setText:selectedString];
            [cutFieldsMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:currentlySelectedTag-1 withObject:selectedString]; //replace first string with second string in the arrayg
        }
    }

    currentlySelectedTag ++;
    if (totalCutCount < currentlySelectedTag) {
        currentlySelectedTag = 1;
    }
    // reset tags so that you can set the correctly
    totalCount = 0; // zero this out so that the next time the view is loaded you can get an accurate count of cuts
    labelTag = 1;
    labelPositionTag = 1001;

    [self.tableView reloadData];


    // test code to see if I can access the UIScrollView to move its scroll position using the Label object I cast at the start of this method
    // this code is not working.
    UIScrollView *temptemp = ((UIScrollView *)label.superview.superview); // this equals nil

    // Sort out new position
    float newPosition = ((UIScrollView *)label.superview.superview).contentOffset.x+label.superview.superview.frame.size.width;
    CGRect toVisible = CGRectMake(newPosition, 0, label.superview.superview.frame.size.width, label.superview.superview.frame.size.height);
    // perform scroll to new position
    [(UIScrollView *)label.superview.superview scrollRectToVisible:toVisible animated:YES];

}
```

I have also tried print a output of the view hierarchy to see if using .superview.superview is correct and this is a copy and paste of the selected object/view

***UPDATE

```
<UIScrollView: 0x1676d560; frame = (0 0; 320 77); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16636b20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x16659970>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x16637280; frame = (0 0; 404 18); layer = <CALayer: 0x16643980>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x16655da0; frame = (0 0; 414 77); layer = <CALayer: 0x16643950>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x166ce3b0; frame = (2 35; 40 40); text = ' '; clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x166cf650>; layer = <CALayer: 0x16645dc0>>
```

which I am now wondering if the cast of the label in my symbolButtonPressed method dose not allow access to superviews?

Comment: Your original code shows you adding the label to a view that is added to a `UIScrollView`. Then your update shows the label inside a table cell. Those aren't even close to similar.

Comment: well, My original code shows how I created the object hierarchy, Then I realised it is obviously going to help if I also show you how I have tried to access this UIScrollView through the UILabel I casted in the method... dose this make sense? sorry if i have done this wrong.

Comment: No, this makes no sense. How did the label move from the scroll view to a table cell?

Comment: ahhhhh... damnit I saw scroll view part of it and thought that was the hierarchy... okay let me look into the view hierarchy now and will replace that part of the code. To tell you why I am reloading the tableview is because I add each UIScrollview into its own UItableViewCell of a UITable.. so I have scrolling up and down then left and right. One moment while i go over the hierarchy output

Comment: ahha!!! I found the objects I was after.... So the UILabel is what I Have access too (via a cast type ( i think thats the correct wording for it)) I would like to though get access to the UIScrollView using that label i have casted in the method i added to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way would be:

```
UILabel *label = ... // the reference to your label
UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)label.superview.superview.superview;
```

This code assumes a fixed hierarchy of your views. There are safer ways to walk up a view's superviews until you find the proper parent view.

Comment: oh right, I got as far as going label.superview but did not think that you could just add another .superview good to know, I will try it now.

Comment: okay, so that did not work for me which makes me thing I have the Hierarchy wrong.. I am going to look back through my code but I was woundering if there is a way to log the hieracry of an object inside xcode terminal.. sorry fluked out and found it I can use **po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]**

Comment: I am just going to update my question as I think I missed out important information regarding how I access the UILabel which I didnt think was important to begin with but maybe it is.

Comment: Would the down voter please care to explain? No one learns if you simply down vote for no reason.

Comment: I gave you the upvote.. then I took it away as your answer is not working for my situation, thats why I added more details to my question to help. I'll add the upvote back its just If someone comes and looks at this question I do not want them to think that this answer worked for the question I asked... If I am wrong in doing that I am sorry I will add the upvote back its just I am trying to use this site correctly... I just expected your answer to work cause it made logical sense.. in retrospect I upvoted you too quickly, Sorry about that.

Comment: Undoing an up vote is quite different from down voting. Someone, other than you, down voted for an unknown reason. BTW - see my comment under your question. Your question no longer makes any sense.

Comment: also maybe I just downvoted you.. Im sure though I originally upvoted you. I will change it when/if this answer is able to help solve the question.. but at the moment its just scrollview is returning nill atm..

Comment: Based on your updated output, you need one more call to `superview`.